# Is there an arcpy boolean check for whether an EPSG or prj is supported by arcmap?

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system, geoprocessing, epsg

I'm writing a tool and essentially I found out that arcmap defaults an epsg to 0 if it sees that the projection is not supported against the predefined projections.

Comment: Have you checked out the SpatialReference Class documentation at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/000v/000v000000p6000000.htm ?  No answer jumps out at me from there but coordinate systems are not my forte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the following code and see what happens using a not supported EPSG code:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference()
sr.factoryCode = 123
sr.create()
```

May be you can check any property of the `sr` object to see if the given EPSG code `123` was valid. May be the `create()` method raises an exception. Have a try :-)